# User added and changeable data that gets saved after app gets closed

Tags: java, string

Is it possible to write a code so that the user can add and change names to a checklist and that the names will be saved even after the app gets closed? How should it look like? It is my first time programming in android studio and I could not find any answer

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. You can either:

1. Output the contents of the checklist to a file and then have the application read from that file every time it starts up.

OR

2. Save the contents of the checklist to a database.

The former is a lot easier for a small-scale personal app, but the latter is definitely more useful for large-scale application development.

To see how to read/write from/to a file, you can read this:

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java.html